# Context Output into CSV file

Tags: csv, powershell, powershell-2.0, export-to-csv

I need to search 10-15 strings into the entire application codes(more than 10000 programs) so I have inserted the strings that i need to search in a text file "strings.text".  I also need to know the previous and next line of the matched string line so I am using "Context 1" in the below script. However, the below script is giving output as only Matched String line.

```
$content = Get-Content strings.txt
ForEach ($Word in $content){
  Get-ChildItem -recurse |
    Select-String -pattern $Word -Context 1 |
    Select-  path,line,linenumber,filename |
    Export-csv -Path "\result_$word.csv"
}
```

Output:

```
Path                Line          LineNumber   FileName
desktop\prog1.txt   Server(xyz)   3            prog1.txt
desktop\prog2.txt   Server(xyz)   6            prog2.txt
```

What I really want is:

```
Path                Line          LineNumber   FileName
                    Connect       2            prog1.txt
desktop\prog1.txt   Server(xyz)   3            prog1.txt
                    stop          4            prog1.txt

                    Connect       8            prog2.txt
desktop\prog2.txt   Server(xyz)   9            prog2.txt
                    stop          10           prog2.txt
```

Can anyone please help how can I get this output? Please suggest if there is any other way to get the required output.

Comment: Ask yourself: if you can't be bothered to put effort into your question, why would anyone else? Not to mention that proper formatting is crucial for understanding what your desired result is.

Comment: Really sorry for the formatting. I tried it as per instructions but it did not work. Thanks for editing it in proper format, really appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to export to a CSV you need to create separate objects for each CSV line. Try something like this:

```
foreach ($Word in $content){
  Get-ChildItem -Recurse |
    Select-String -Pattern $Word -Context 1 |
    ForEach-Object {
      New-Object -Type PSCustomObject -Property @{
        Path       = ''
        Line       = $_.Context.PreContext[-1]
        LineNumber = $_.LineNumber - 1
        Filename   = $_.FileName
      }
      New-Object -Type PSCustomObject -Property @{
        Path       = $_.Path
        Line       = $_.Line
        LineNumber = $_.LineNumber
        Filename   = $_.FileName
      }
      New-Object -Type PSCustomObject -Property @{
        Path       = ''
        Line       = $_.Context.PostContext[0]
        LineNumber = $_.LineNumber + 1
        Filename   = $_.FileName
      }
    } | Export-Csv -Path "\result_$word.csv" -NoType
}
```

`$_.Context.PreContext[-1]` is the last line of the pre-context, `$_.Context.PostContext[0]` is the first line of the post-context.

Comment: Yes, it worked. I just had to remove `-Append -NoType -Delimiter "`t"`  As with this, the output in CSV file is in one column only. By removing it, the output is coming out properly in columns. Thanks for your help.

Comment: ohh, my bad. Problem is, I need to run it on powershell 2.0 where I can not use `-append` do you have any alternative to this?

Comment: Mmh, scratch that. `Export-Csv` is at the end of the pipeline for each word, so `-Append` shouldn't be needed here. Fixed.

Comment: Thanks Ansgar. I should have checked second time without asking you. Yes, Its fixed. Thanks, Again.